# mapオペレータがimportできない

Tags: node.js, angularjs, rx-javascript

Angularのプロジェクトでmapオペレータをimportしているにもかかわらず、下記のエラーが表示されます。

```
error TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?
```

ソースコードは以下の通りです。

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';//mapオペレータのimport
import { SessionService } from '../service/session.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private session: SessionService,
    private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.session
      .checkLoginState()//SessionのObservableを返す
      .pipe(
        map(session => {
          // ログインしていない場合はログイン画面に遷移
          if (!session.login) {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
          }
         return session.login;
       })
      )
  }
```

Comment: 状況を再現しようとしてみましたが、残念ながらできませんでした。恐らく [こちらの一連の記事](https://qiita.com/Yamamoto0525/items/a76ea4b3924eeb82b0f9) を参考にしていらっしゃると思いますが、より詳細な情報が必要です。「 **ライブラリのバージョンはどうなっているか** 」、「 **どういう操作をしたらそのエラーが表示されるのか** 」、「 **抜粋ではなくエラーの全文（ファイルパスの情報なども含めて）** 」を教えていただけないでしょうか。（質問文に追記していただければ結構です。）

Comment: rxjsが5なのかもしれませんね（ObservableはそれでもImport可能） `import { map } from 'rxjs/operator/map';` でimportできるか試されると良いかもしれません。6か5かで違いがありますので、参考にされるサイトと合わせられるといいでしょう（Angularのバージョンを合わせれば合うと思います。